# Apache ModRewrite full url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have an single question, can mod-rewrite rewrite full URL param?

http://example.com/go/something/after/go   - works fine.

http://example.com/go/http%3A%2F%2Ftarget.com%2Fpage%3Fid%3D8900  - responses 404 error

Current .htaccess rules in /go folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule (.*) /go/go.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  not rewrite/redirect `%3F` (encoded slash) unless `encoded slashes` are enabled on your apache server. To enable encoded slashes, add the following directive to your `server.config` or `virtual host` context.

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

From the apache manual:

The `AllowEncodedSlashes` directive allows URLs which contain encoded path separators (%2F for / and additionally %5C for \ on accordant systems) to be used in the path info.
With the default value, Off, such URLs are refused with a `404 (Not found)` error.
With the value On, such URLs are accepted, and encoded slashes are decoded like all other encoded characters.
With the value NoDecode, such URLs are accepted, but encoded slashes are not decoded but left in their encoded state.
Turning AllowEncodedSlashes On is mostly useful when used in conjunction with `PATH_INFO`

**Note**

If encoded slashes are needed in path info, use of NoDecode is strongly recommended as a security measure. Allowing slashes to be decoded could potentially allow unsafe paths